# Number of primes within a number of given length

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

My question is most easily explained via an example: Consider the number $n=1967$. It contains the prime numbers $7$, $19$, $67$ and $967$ as all those are primes and you can find them in the decimal expansion of $1967$. In contrast, the part $196$ for example is not prime.

Given a fixed number of digits, $k$ say, what can be said about the maximal number of primes you can find in the decimal expansion of a $k$-digit number? I will call this number $m(k)$. The above example then teaches us that $m(4)\ge 4$.

Clearly, $m(k) \ge k$ e.g. by considering the number with digit $3$ $k$-times. The same argument shows that $m(k+1)\ge m(k)+1$. The maximal number of subnumbers for a $k$-digit number is $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, so trivially $m(k)\le \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$.

The first cases are:
$$m(1)=1\ (e.g. n=3)\\
m(2)=3\ (e.g. n=23)\\
m(3)=6\ (e.g. n=373).$$

Comment: Do the prime numbers have to be distinct?

Comment: @Matti, apparently not, because of what he said of considering digit $3\ k$ times

Comment: @MattiP.: No, primes do not have to be distinct.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know how about digit '$0$' using (for example, $307$: $3, 7$,  $\color{gray}{07}$(???) and $307$). 
Therefore all examples below are without this digit.

Few bounds with examples:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|l|}
\hline
k & m(k) & \frac{k(k+1)}{2} & examples \\
\hline
4 & 9 & 10 & ... \\
5 & 13 & 15 & 31373, 37337 \\
6 & 17 & 21 & 337397, 373373, 373379 \\
7 & 22 & 28 & 3733797 \\
8 & 26 & 36 & 37337397 \\
9 & 30 & 45 & 113733797, 233133733, 373373977, 733133733 \\
10 & 35 & 55 & 2113733797, 3733133733, 7331337337 \\
11 & \ge 40 & 66 & 17331337337, 37331337337, 37337937337, 52379337397, ... \\
12 & \ge 45 & 78 & 337331237337, 361373371973, 373312373373, 373313373379, ... \\
13 & \ge 51 & 91 & 1117331337337, 3373312373373 \\
14 & \ge 56 & 105 & 11173313373373, 31379719337397, 32917333739397, 33733123733739 \\
15 & \ge 62 & 120 & 329173337393739, 337331237337397 \\
16 & \ge 68 & 136 & 3291733373937397 \\
17 & \ge 74 & 153 & 31973373312373373 \\
18 & \ge 80 & 171 & 331973373312373373 \\
19 & \ge 85 & 190 & 1373363733123733739, 1731373973373937397, 2331127997337337973, ... \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots 
\end{array}

For $k\ge 11$ the search was not exhaustive.

Comment: I guess one could argue that 07 should be counted as well as 7. Otherwise you would decrease the maximal number of subnumbers possible for every 0 within the number.

Comment: Interestingly, the lower bound you found still only grows linearly.

Comment: Probably, the given values are near the optimum, if not the optimum.

Answer (score 0):

I made a python script to check if the natural upper bound is always reached. The answer seems to be no:

Answer (for each $k$ from 1 to 5):

$[1, 3, 6, 9, 13]$

Natural upper bound (for each $k$ from 1 to 5):

$[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]$

Comment: script: http://pasted.co/4f687732

Comment: Is your scipt able to compute $m(k)$ for large (how large?) values of $k$? This would at least give an intuition of what to expect.

Comment: nah, it takes too long for $k \geq 7$. Maybe I could do a more intelligent algorithm (or explore random numbers)...